# html + css, display text and wrap it propertly in two columns and a single row

Tags: html, css, text

I have a container in html that will display a label with its value with the following rules:

**Case 1:** the container has a fixed width and in this particular instance the label and the value fit perfectly.

```
container
+-----------------------------------+
|  label         value              |
| +------------+-----------+        |
| | Birthdate: | 17/7/2007 |        |
| +------------+-----------+        |
+-----------------------------------+
```

**Case 2:** if I translate the label and the result text is 'larger' it shoud behave like this:

```
container
+-----------------------------------+
|  label                 value      |
| +--------------------+-----------+|
| | Fecha de cumpl...: | 17/7/2007 ||
| +--------------------+-----------+|
+-----------------------------------+
```

In Case 2, the label grew up to a certain limit where it stops the value to jump into the next line. The text then has ellipsis to display that the text was 'larger'.

**Case 3:**  this case will show that the size of the value container has the priority here. This is what happens when the value field content text is 'larger' than the label content text.

```
container
+-----------------------------------+
|  label              value         |
| +----------------+---------------+|
| | Fecha de c...: | no disponible ||
| +----------------+---------------+|
+-----------------------------------+
```

So finally here the value container width changes to fit its content and lable adapts the most it cans before applying ellipsis on itself.

Yet again in case 3 but in English locale:

```
container
+-----------------------------------+
|  label              value         |
| +------------+---------------+    |
| | Birthdate: | not available |    |
| +------------+---------------+    |
+-----------------------------------+
```

The display then is the same as in Case 1.

How can I achieve this behavior with CSS? I was trying a solution where the value container floats to the right and then the label one takes the remaining space on the left... It works ok for case 2 and 3 but not for 1 where there is a resulting 'large' whitespace in the middle between the text of the label and the text of the value.

Could you please help me out with any information? I would really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your html and css that you have tried? (And/or a jsfiddle) That will make it easier to recreate what you are talking about.

Comment: use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` with fixed `width`.

Comment: @KheemaPandey wow I didn't even know that existed. I'll be sure to check that out next time ellipsis come into play.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzK7H/) that you can play with and adjust the sizes as you see fit.

Comments:

- I tend to be a purist in terms of using tables for layout, but in
  this case it worked out OK.

  I put a div in the td so you could use ellipsis.

CSS

```
table {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
table td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
div {
   width: 100px;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hi @TimSPQR, thanks for your answer... in order to make it fully comply with Case 3 I had to make a modification to the table td style and add a white-space: nowrap; style on it... this way the text on the second column doesn't jump to a second line. I will edit this in your answer css!

Comment: I am testing it again ... in Case 1 you can see a very big space of separation between the laben when it is very small and the value. This is because TD's are taking the space es 50% of the width and not the length of their contents.

Comment: Continue testing and repost your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I am doing something like this... it is not perfect particularly in cases like 2 but it will do for the moment.

```
<div class="container">
   <div>
      <strong class="l-ellipsis">the-label</strong>
      <span class="c-ellipsis">the-content</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <strong class="l-ellipsis">the-label</strong>
      <span class="c-ellipsis">the-content</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

The css is like this:

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.container div {
    clear: both;
}
.l-ellipsis, .c-ellipsis {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.l-ellipsis {
   border: 1px dotted red;
   max-width: 50%;
   width: auto;
   margin-right: 2px;
}
.c-ellipsis {
    border: 1px dotted green;
   max-width: 50%;
   width: auto;
}
```

The fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/9q744/